# listview not showing anything flutter

Tags: list, flutter, listview

this is my code

```
List<Widget> text = [];
int number = 0;
```

this is my method

```
void tekan() {
    setState(() {
      text.add(Text("data" + number.toString()));
      number++;
    });
  }
```

this is the listview code

```
Expanded(
         child: ListView(
         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
         children: text,
))
```

can anyone tell me where is the wrong code? because when i used the code above, the list view just return blank screen

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Expanded` and try the below code.

```
ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: text,
      ),
```

Comment: it's working but the listview is not updating

Comment: can you please elaborate more about issue?